# store input of line edit to string qt

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit

I'm a beginner.I am making a simple gui program using qt in which you enter a url/website and that program will open that webpage in chrome.I used line edit in which user enters url and i used `returnPressed()` slot, but the problem is (it might sound stupid)  that i don't know how to take the input by user and store it in a string so that i can pass that string as parameter to chrome.Is im asking something wrong.also tell me how can i save input to a txt file, i know how to do that in a console program.Is this process is same with others like text edit etc.
My mainwindow.cpp:

```
    QString exeloc = "F:\\Users\\Amol-2\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe";

void MainWindow::on_site_returnPressed()
{
    QString site;
    getwchar(site);
    QString space=" ";
    QString result = exeloc + space + site;
    QProcess::execute(result);

}
```

What im doing wrong.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QLineEdit` has a [`text()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qlineedit.html#text-prop) function that will return a `QString`. So you can do something like this:

```
QString site = ui->site->text();
```

You don't have to use `QProcess` to open a web site in a browser. You can use [`QDesktopServices::openUrl`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl) static function.

Like this:

```
QString site = ui->site->text();
QUrl url(site);
QDesktopServices::openUrl(url);
```

Remember to include `QDesktopServices` and `QUrl` headers:

```
#include <QDesktopServices>
#include <QUrl>
```

Comment: hey its giving me the followingF:\Users\Amol-2\Desktop\Imp Docs\C++ apps\QtMainLProject\mainwindow.cpp:27: error: variable 'QUrl url' has initializer but incomplete type
     QUrl url(site); what should i do now
                  ^ character:<br>

Comment: @user3251645 `#include <QUrl>`

Answer (score 1):

You've got your approach slightly wrong, I can see where you're coming from though. It's actually a lot more simple than you're trying, Qt has a `QDesktopServices` class that allows you to interact with various system items, including open urls in the browser. [There's documentation on it here](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl).